# What does "omnibus dehiscens offendiculum" mean?

Tags: classical-latin, medieval-latin, academic-latin

I came across this phrase in *Historia Hierosolymitana* by Baldricus Dolensis (c. 1050–1130): omnibus dehiscens offendiculum. What does this sentence mean? I would appreciate any help.

Here is more context in case it helps:

> Qui præ nimia tristitia, strictim complosis manibus et stridentes dentibus ingemiscebant. Labebantur equi in immane præcipitium, et trames artissimus pepererat/præparabat ***omnibus dehiscens offendiculum.*** 
>   Multi vel equis, vel clitellariis, cum rebus superpositis, illic amissis, pauperati sunt.

Comment: Where is this from? Do you have any context?

Comment: I study on this text : Baldricus Dolensis (c.1050–1130), Historia Hierosolymitana

Comment: Can you add that information to the question? Your own thoughts on translating would be good to have, too, whatever they are. That helps write an answer that helps you.

Comment: How does the English sentence "The narrowest road prevent/hinder to all men" relate to the Latin one? Is it a translation (by you, Google or something else) or some kind of context?

Comment: happen by mistake sorry.

Comment: It's hard to translate a short sentence without context -- can you post some of the surrounding text?

Comment: ok thank you.Qui præ nimia tristitia, strictim complosis manibus et stridentes dentibus ingemiscebant. Labebantur equi in immane præcipitium, et trames artissimus pepererat/præparabat omnibus dehiscens offendiculum. 
Multi vel equis, vel clitellariis, cum rebus superpositis, illic amissis, pauperati sunt.

Comment: Thank you for providing more context! I reformatted your question. Feel free to edit again if you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me translate sentence by sentence.
Second opinions (and answers) are welcome.

> *Qui præ nimia tristitia, strictim complosis manibus et stridentes dentibus ingemiscebant.*
>   They groaned because of too much grief, clapping their hands tightly and creaking their teeth.

This may or may not be idiomatic English, but I hope the message is clear.

> *Labebantur equi in immane præcipitium, et trames artissimus pepererat/præparabat omnibus dehiscens offendiculum.*
>   Horses fell down an enormous cliff and the extremely narrow path created a wide obstacle for everyone.

This sounds like a problem at a mountain path.
Horses fall down and a part of the path collapses, leaving a wide gap in the path.
[*Offendiculum*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2040206) means an obstacle, and in this context I think it is more likely to be a hole than a block on the road.
*Dehiscens* is the present participle of [*dehiscere*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2015984), "to open up".
Either the path opens up and produces the obstacle, or the obstacle produced by the path opens up.
I cannot tell for sure whether *dehiscens* modifies *trames* or *offendiculum*.
It does not really make a big difference for translation or interpretation, though.

> *Multi vel equis, vel clitellariis, cum rebus superpositis, illic amissis, pauperati sunt.*
>   Many lost horses or pack-saddles and the things on them and were thus impoverished.

People's possessions fell down and were lost.
I am not sure if it means short term possessions like travel gear or long term possessions if they were traveling with all they got.
As with the previous sentences, more context would help me find the most suitable translation, but this level of accuracy might be enough.

In this context, I might translate the key phrase *omnibus dehiscens offendiculum* as "a gaping obstacle for everyone" or something in that direction.
Or perhaps even "a hole in the path that no one could pass", depending on how you want to use the translation.

Comment: Thank you Mr Joonas IImavirta for your help. I can translate other sentences but "omnibus dehiscens offendiculum"  is very troublesome. Thank you again

Comment: Artissimus = extremely narrow (artus).

Comment: @turuncu, I'm glad if I could help. For future questions like this (and why not this one, too), I suggest adding your own translations of the surrounding text. That would achieve two things: Answering becomes easier and people see that you genuinely want to solve the problem but could not make it yourself.

Comment: @TKR, thanks! Will edit. I wonder why I missed that word in two dictionaries.

Comment: I wonder if there are many other situations where both *altissimus* and *artissimus* would make sense. (And not only to Elmer Fudd.)

Comment: I don't think *dehiscens offendiculum* is a reference to the path collapsing, but a description of the path itself, which is an "obstacle" in the sense that it's too narrow for the large number of people (*omnibus*), and is "opening downward" because it's leading down the mountain. At least, that's my best guess -- *dehiscens* is a little puzzling.

Comment: Yes it's true, dehiscens very puzzling. Dehiscens means in English gape/yawn/split open; part/divide, develop/leave a gap/leak; be/become apart. Thank you.

Comment: @TKR, that is one option. In that reading *offendiculum* would mean a narrow path, not a particular difficult spot on it, and *dehiscens* would refer to the overall location of the path, not a hole in it. That leaves room for interpretation. I don't fully understand how the path can be too narrow to a large number of people, though. If there is no compelling reason to go side by side, a queue can go where a single person can.

Comment: Maybe there's a large number of people and they're in a hurry? We don't know what's going on in this passage.

Comment: @TKR, that is possible. But true, we can only guess. It would make sense to explore more options to give a fuller answer, but I have to call it a day.